# Rearrangement in proof for Euler's formula

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

In the proof for Euler's formula, we expand $e^{ix}$ as a Taylor series, rearrange the terms, factor out $i$, and thus obtain the Taylor series for $\sin (x)$ and $\cos(x)$. However, this rearrangement can only be done if the Taylor series for $e^{ix}$ is absolutely convergent, by the Riemann series theorem.

I know how to prove that a series of real terms is absolutely convergent. However, how do you do the same for a series of complex terms, like the one obtained in the Taylor series expansion of $e^{ix}$?

Comment: The same way as for real series?

Comment: By that I mean, how do you prove that a series of complex terms is either conditionally or absolutely convergent?

Comment: But some series of complex terms are divergent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complex numbers work the same way $\mathbb{R}^2$ does as a [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) but the generalization is the same for $\mathbb{R}^n$, we pass from the point to its length by using the distance function induced by the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). This often requires repeated use of the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) but the flow of the argument remains essentially the same for the multivariable Taylor series.

Answer (score 5):

Rearrangements are not the issue here. The basic result is this:

Thm: Suppose $z_n=x_n+iy_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers, where $x_n,y_n$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z_n.$ Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n$ converges in $\mathbb C$ iff both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n$ converge in $\mathbb R.$ In the case of convergence we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\right )+i\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n\right).$$

This implies Euler's formula for $e^{ix}.$

Comment: In response to a comment that is now deleted: We have $e^{ix}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(ix)^n/n!.$ The series of real parts is $1+0-x^2/2!+0+x^4/4!+0=\cdots$ The series of imaginary parts is $0+x+0-x^3/3!+0+x^5/5!+0+\cdots.$ So from the basic result I mentioned,

$$e^{ix}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(ix)^n/n!$$ $$= \left (1+0-x^2/2!+0+x^4/4!+0+\cdots\right )$$ $$ +i\left(0+x+0-x^3/3!+0+x^5/5!+0+\cdots\right) = \cos x +i\sin x.$$

Answer (score 1):

First, the series for $e^{it}$ does converge absolutely: $$\sum\frac{|it|^n}{n!}
=\sum\frac{|t|^n}{n!}=e^{|t|}<\infty.$$More important, this doesn't matter, because there are no rearrangements in the proof. We just use this:

> > If $\sum z_{2n}$ and $\sum z_{2n+1}$ both converge, then so does $\sum z_n$, with $\sum z_n=\sum z_{2n}+\sum z_{2n+1}$.

Proof: Define $$a_n=\begin{cases}z_n,&(n\text{ even}),
\\0,&n\text{ odd}.\end{cases}$$Let $b_n=z_n-a_n$. Then $z_n=a_n+b_n$, hence $\sum z_n=\sum a_n+\sum b_n$.

The "rearrangements" in Riemann's theorem are sums of the form $$\sum_nz_{\sigma(n)},$$where $\sigma:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is a bijection. Nothing like that here...